# S-nail email reply put reply below original message

Tags: configuration, email

I'm using [s-nail](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=s-nail&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) for mail, and when replying to an email the original message is being placed above the reply. Is there a way to place the reply first?